# Quantlib USDLibor, how does it knows which is the correct fixing date?

Tags: c++, date, reset, quantlib

When pricing floating rate bonds, one needs to work with instances of the USDLibor class and adding new fixings given a date (which is equivalent to the last reset date minus two business days). However, sometimes it complaints on runtime telling the user that the fixing for a specified date is not available (meaning that one has provided the fixing for a wrong date).

How do instances of USDLibor know which is correct date? I ask this because maybe I can sort this problem by retrieving the correct date directly as USDLibor gets it working around the problem of figuring out the correct date.

Answer (score 0):

The fixing date is two business days before the reset date, as you said (the implementation of the logic is in the `FloatingRateCoupon::fixingDate()` method, if you want to check it).

However, you might be using the wrong business days. USD LIBOR is fixed in London, so holidays are determined according to the UK calendar, not the US calendar.

In any case, once you have built the bond, you can ask the cashflows themselves for their fixings dates with something like this (which I haven't tested, so it might not even compile, but you should get the idea):

```
using namespace QuantLib;

Leg cashflows = bond.cashflows();
std::vector<Date> fixingDates;
for (Size i=0; i<cashflows.size(); ++i) {
    boost::shared_ptr<FloatingRateCoupon> coupon =
        boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<FloatingRateCoupon>(cashflows[i]);
    if (coupon)
        fixingDates.append(coupon->fixingDate());
}
```

after which the `fixingDates` vector will contain (not surprisingly) the fixing dates.